# show Excel data from another to main application class and show in Datagridview and in combobox

Tags: c#, database, methods, datagridview, combobox

I got a large .xls file which contain many columns including city name population name etc.For my code purpose I only extract the city name and population number from this excell file. I made another class with a method which will do the modification of .xls file.Now in the main Form1.cs I want to show that value at first in datagridview table as two column Like city and population and then from datagridview I want to show the city name in combobox list. I wrote a code for this. But it is showing a lot of error.

To get the excel data I wrote the following code

```
 public class Data
  {
    public string DataService(DataTable data)//showing error
    {

        var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
        string SavedfileName = "POI_list.json";
        var Saving_path = Path.Combine(folderName, SavedfileName);

        string fileName = "Zensus_Gemeinden_org.xlsx";
        var path = Path.Combine(startPath, fileName);

        String name = "Gemeinden_31.12.2011_Vergleich";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                       path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select [3] as City,[4] as Population, * From [" + name + "$D7:E11300] Where [4] > 10000", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        //DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);

        string Place_Json = "Place_List:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(Saving_path, Place_Json);

        return data;//showing error
      }
   }
 }
```

Now  to get this value from main class in datagrid view and combobox I wrote following code

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private readonly Data _DataService;// showing error

    public Form1()
    {

         _DataService=new Data();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        dataGridView1.DataSource = //here I want to set data from DataService method);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)//showing error for 'for'
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(data.Rows[i]["City"]);
        }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataService method signature is public **string** DataService(DataTable data).
But you trying to return DataTable

EDIT:
Just modify your method:

```
public DataTable DataService()
{
    var data = new DataTable();
    var startPath = Application.StartupPath;
    string folderName = Path.Combine(startPath, "POI_List");
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
    string SavedfileName = "POI_list.json";
    var Saving_path = Path.Combine(folderName, SavedfileName);

    string fileName = "Zensus_Gemeinden_org.xlsx";
    var path = Path.Combine(startPath, fileName);

    String name = "Gemeinden_31.12.2011_Vergleich";
    String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                   path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select [3] as City,[4] as Population, * From [" + name + "$D7:E11300] Where [4] > 10000", con);
    con.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
    //DataTable data = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(data);

    string Place_Json = "Place_List:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(Saving_path, Place_Json);
    return data;
  }
```

}

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
```

{
    private readonly Data _data;

```
public Form1()
{

     _data = new Data();

    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var dataTable = _data.DataService()
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable ;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)//showing error for 'for'
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dataTable.Rows[i]["City"]);
    }

 }
```

}

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more. I am quite new handling this situation.

Comment: You trying to return object name "data" of type DataTable.

Comment: If I write string data instead of datatable does it become more suitable. I trying to put everything but could not get anything without error.